# Update the context line upon loading new data d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created a line chart that updates with new data that was based on this example
https://bl.ocks.org/EfratVil/92f894ac0ba265192411e73f633a3e2f/645d58cad06fb8408a85afea3f5dc893d949ebc9

While I've been able to update the main line, I cannot for the life of me get the context line below to update as well. Following the example here is the code to create the two lines

```
    var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([
        [0, 0],
        [width, height2]
    ])
    .on("brush end", brushed);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([
        [0, 0],
        [width, height]
    ])
    .extent([
        [0, 0],
        [width, height]
    ])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

line = d3.line()
    .defined(function(d) {
        return d[trace] != null;
    })
    .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.DATE_PST);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return y(+d[trace]);
    });

line2 = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return x2(d.DATE_PST);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return y2(+d[trace]);
    });

var clip = svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("svg:rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0);


var Line_chart = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");


var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");



x.domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.DATE_PST));
y.domain([d3.min(data, d => +d[trace]), d3.max(data, d => +d[trace])]);
x2.domain(x.domain());
y2.domain(y.domain());


focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

yaxe = focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(yAxis);




Line_chart.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line)
    .style("stroke", function() {
        if(met.includes(trace)){
            c = 'red'
        }else{
            c = 'steelblue'
        }
     return c });

context.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line2")
    .attr("id", "line2")
    .attr("d", line2)
    .style("stroke", function() {
        if(met.includes(trace)){
            c = 'red'
        }else{
            c = 'steelblue'
        }
     return c });;


context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
    .call(xAxis2);

context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.move, x.range());

focus1 = focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus1")
    .style("display", "none");
// .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
// .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

focus1.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3);

focus1.append("text")
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "zoom")
    .attr("id", "overlay")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom)
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        focus1.style("display", null);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
        focus1.style("display", "none");
    })
    .on("mousemove", mousemove);
```

and to update the Line_chart with the new data:

```
Line_chart = d3.select("g").transition();

Line_chart.select(".line")
    .duration(750)
    .attr("d", line)
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
        if(met.includes(trace)){
            c = 'red'
        }else{
            c = 'steelblue'
        }
     return c });;
```

I've tried many variations to update the context line but have had no luck:

```
 context = d3.select("g").transition();
context.select(".line2")
.duration(750)
.attr("d", line2)
.style("stroke", function(d) {
    console.log(d)
    if(met.includes(trace)){
        c = 'red'
    }else{
        c = 'steelblue'
    }
 return c });
```

How do I update the context line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code provided your error is here:

```
context = d3.select("g").transition();
```

When updating the main area (focus) you use:

```
Line_chart = d3.select("g").transition();
```

But, when updating the context (lower section), you use the same selection:

```
context = d3.select("g").transition();
```

`d3.select` will traverse the DOM until it finds an element that matches the selector. It will select the same g for each of these statements because `d3.select` selects only one matching DOM element, the first one it encounters. The first `g` you have is the `Line_Chart` `g`.

As it selects the same element each time, you will never update the second or later `g`s. Furthermore, you are searching the first `g` for a line with the class `line2` (.select(".line2")), as this class exists only in a later `g`, it will always return a null selection - therefore nothing will be updated. One option would be to remove the reference to the `g` altogether and select the line with a unique identifier - assuming there is only one line with that class :

```
d3.select(".line2") // or better yet, svg.select() as it is in the svg
.transition()
.duration(750)
.attr("d", line2)
.style("stroke", function(d) {
    console.log(d)
    if(met.includes(trace)){
        c = 'red'
    }else{
        c = 'steelblue'
    }
 return c });
```

If you really want to keep the current structure, you could assign an id to the context `g`:

```
var context = svg.append("g")
   .attr("id","context")
```

And then select that id later when updating the line:

```
context = d3.select("#context").transition();
context.select(".line2")
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or gist that reproduces the issue that I can see?

Comment: Actually, I'm making progress. When I appended the data to the context I still had the class as line, not line.     context.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "line2"). seems to be working. If I have any more issues I'll setup as a bl.ock. Thanks, Andrew